# ip in SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation is dynamic, sometimes it's not client ip

Tags: mysql, pdo, ip, host

I use php pdo to select from a non exist db, get an error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'xxx'@'10.80.109.181' for table 'e_trade'.

the strange thing is the ip after @ is dynamic, not the client ip,What are the reasons? I am so confused, thanks a lot.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twIYx.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11FaK.png)

Comment: Ask your database admin to grant SELECT to % instead of localhost for the user account you're using. This will allow you access from any IP address.

Comment: the "client IP" in this case is your web server.

Comment: The user is allowed to access databases, my problem is if the db in the select sql is non exist, so the error occured, but i can not understand why the client ip change very often.

Comment: Your user is only granted permission on specific databases. If you grant to `*.*` that's all databases, see if the error goes away.

Comment: yes, you are right. the user is only granted permission on specific databases. my ip is 10.25.169.93, but the ip in error can be SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'airent_db_x'@'10.30.192.245' for table 'e_trade,            SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'airent_db_x'@'10.80.228.225' for table 'e_trade',           SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'airent_db_x'@'10.80.109.181' for table 'e_trade'

Comment: The IPs are all private IP address ranges most likely assigned by your LAN DHCP. Did you see all of these different IPs within a short period of time or long period?

Comment: All the ips are our private ip for different machines. I connect to mysql at server ip 10.25.169.93, but in the errrors it usually show other servers' private ip, every time i run the php code, it always changes ip in error.